# phantomjs waitFor code not working

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using this waitFor function (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) to try to submit a form before continuing.  The web page I'm loading has a modal box that requires that I accept a cookie policy before going.  The modal box is a form element and when I do the following in my browser, the box goes away and I can then use the page:

```
document.getElementById("terms_form").submit();
```

Therefore, I thought I should be able to do this in phantomjs:

```
page.open('http://thiswebpage.com/', function(status){
  if(status === "success"){
    page.evaluate(function(){
      document.getElementById("terms_form").submit();
      waitFor(function(){  
        return document.getElementById("terms_form") == null; }, 
              function () { page.render('aftersubmit.png'); });
    });
  } else { console.log ("status: "+status) }
  phantom.exit();
}
```

So, what's strange to me is that aftersumbit.png is never created.  So there's something fundamentally wrong with my code.  I'm also not seeing any console log messages from waitFor.

I must be missing something obvious but I've been stuck on it for quite a while so I thought I'd ask for help.  Thanks a million in advance.

To be very clear, in the web-browser after running document.getElementById("terms_form").submit(), the modal box is gone and running the test 'document.getElementById("terms_form") == null' returns True.  Also, I have the definition of waitFor (given at that link, pasted here for convenience) at the top of my file:

```
"use strict";
function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 3000, //< Default Max Timout is 3s
    start = new Date().getTime(),
    condition = false,
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
            // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
            condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
        } else {
            if(!condition) {
                // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                phantom.exit(1);
            } else {
                // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
            }
        }
    }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
};
```

EDIT: I also have page.onError as below:

```
page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
  console.log(msg); 
  trace.forEach(function(item){
    console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
  });
}
```

Yet I don't see any errors being printed.  I'm still a bit lost with this.  I created a small test of the onError handler like this:

```
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg){
  console.log(msg);
}

page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
  console.log(msg);
  trace.forEach(function(item){
    console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
  });
}

page.open('https://google.com/', function(status){
  page.evaluate(function(){
    referenceErrorGenerator.getElementById("foo");
  });
  phantom.exit();
});
```

And that seems to work fine, I see

```
$ phantomjs onerror.js
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: referenceErrorGenerator
```

When I try to run it.

I wonder why my waitFor code is not executing AND not printing any error.

Comment: You have a critical typo in your function: `docuement` -> `document`.

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks.  It turns out that typo was only in this question, my code doesn't have that.

Comment: What's more, I just noticed that even though I have added page.onError as shown here (http://phantomjs.org/troubleshooting.html), I don't actually see any error messages on the console when I purposely introduce an error.  For example, in my web console, typing "docuent.getElementById("foo");" produces an Uncaught ReferenceError, yet putting that docuent typo into my phantomjs code and running it doesn't print any stacktrace, but I thought that the onError code would have printed it.  I must be missing something quite crucial here.

Comment: Check my answer. The `document` does not exist where you're executing this command, so you  get a ReferenceError.

Comment: Any idea why I don't see the ReferenceError in stdout?  should the page.onError handler be printing that?

Answer (score 0):

The `page` exists only in phantomjs scope, not in webpage scope. Rewrite it to execute `page.render` outside of `page.evaluate`.

```
// first execute the submit
page.evaluate(function() {
    document.getElementById("terms_form").submit();
});
// waitFor run outside the page scope
waitFor(function(){
    return page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.getElementById("terms_form") == null;
    })
}, function () { page.render('aftersubmit.png'); });
```

Comment: aha, I will test this.  although, I actually do have the whole thing (inside the if("success") inside a page.evaulate.  I should have put that in my question, I will edit it now.

Comment: So, the problem is the opposite. You don't have `page` to execute `page.render` there.

Comment: Wait, how would I not have page inside a page.evaluate()?

Comment: I updated my answer. Inside the evaluate context, you have only the document context, not the `page`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think I understand now, although I'm still not having success.  There may be other errors in my code,  I think I may need to get the page.onError handler working before I can tackle this as I'm not seeing any reference errors or getting any feedback on stdout and that's making it a bit impossible to find what's wrong.

Comment: Try the remote debugging, it is amazing! http://phantomjs.org/troubleshooting.html

Comment: In fact, I did try that, strangely, I see some output from my script in the console, but I don't actually see any of the lines of my script in the "sources" tab, instead, it just shows and empty pane.  This is in chromium on debian.